# Can't connect to MongoDB with connections string?

Tags: mongodb

Using a bit of an older version of MongoDB (3.3.4) running in EC2 and attempting to connect to it with a mongod:// connection string. For context, I've enabled TSL/SSL with a self signed cert and I can successfully connect with the mongo command line on the Mongo host with this command:

```
mongo --ssl --username "<xxxx>" --password "<xxxxx>" --sslAllowInvalidCertificates --host <host>.us-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017 --sslPEMKeyFile /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem --authenticationDatabase admin
```

I'm trying to make this into a connection string for my app. I've tried this:

```
mongo "mongodb://<user>:<password>@<host>.us-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017/?ssl=true&sslPEMKeyFile=/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem&sslAllowInvalidCertificates=true&authenticationDatabase=admin"
```

This results in:

```
2023-12-18T16:47:18.479+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] Socket recv() Connection reset by peer 172.31.1.1:27017
2023-12-18T16:47:18.479+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: SocketException socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [x.x.x.x:27017]
2023-12-18T16:47:18.479+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host 'ec2-12-192-131-211.us-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017'  :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Within MongoDB Compass on my local dev machine I can connect to it via this command which it creates in the UI when telling it connect with my self signed cert:

```
    mongodb://<user>:<password>@<host>.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:27017/?tls=true&tlsCAFile=/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem

If I hop onto my the MongoDB host I get the same error if I try that connection string:

2023-12-18T16:50:35.581+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] Socket recv() Connection reset by peer 172.31.1.1:27017
2023-12-18T16:50:35.581+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: SocketException socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [172.31.1.1:27017]
2023-12-18T16:50:35.581+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host 'ec2-12-192-131-211.us-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017'  :
```

How do I make a mongod:// connection string that'll allow me to connect to the database??

Comment: what language your app is written in?

Comment: What errors do the mongod log show?

Answer (score 0):

The command line options are slightly different than parameters in connection string. Try

```
tlsCertificateKeyFile=/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem&tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=true&authSource=admin
```

instead of

```
sslPEMKeyFile=/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem&sslAllowInvalidCertificates=true&authenticationDatabase=admin
```